# How to use if condition using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have build application in which I am using csv and I am using these condition but they are very slow. I heard that using pandas it makes it fast , I just want to convert this code into pandas,I search alot but didn't get idea how to use if else condition in pandas

```py
with open("alkhidmat.txt", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    reader = DictReader(f, delimiter=";")

for index, row in enumerate(reader):
    if (
        search_uc == "All"
        and row["Food Package"] == food
        and (row["Category"] == check_category or check_category == "All")
        and (row["Gender"] == check_gender or check_gender == "All")
    ):
        pass
```

This is data in csv File

```
Registration No;Person Name;Father Name;Gender;Persons;Union Council;Address;Date;CNIC;Category;Occupation;Mobile No;Food Package
1;گل محمد خان;محمد اقبال;مرد;7;Kholian Bala;بلڈ ھیر;04/08/2020;1330221680055;دہیاڑی دار مزدور;مزدری;3121582459;Retain
```

I make it more simple
This is a condition which I am using somewhere in my code

```
df.loc[df["CNIC"] == cnic_no, "Food Package"] = "Retain"
```

This condition is if there is any entry of cnic_no == key["CNIC"] then change Food package to retain 
Now I just want a simple condition

```
if df["CNIC"]==cnic_no
```

How can I use this condition using pandas

Comment: provide a sample of your raw file

Comment: done I have edited it

Answer (score 0):

may be converting **DataFrame** into **numpy array** will work.

```
import pandas as pd

# read data from csv file
data = pd.read_csv("Data.csv")
print(type(data))
print(data) # will print the data in dataframe
data = data.values

print("---------")

for row in data:
    row_length = len(row)
    for i in range(row_length):
        if row[i] == "Salman":
            print(row)
```

Output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
     Name  Age Gender
0  Deepak   24   Male
1    Tony   45   Male
2  Salman   50   Male
---------
['Salman' 50 'Male']
```

Comment: @Osama have a look at this example. it may work for you.

Comment: Again if I have 4000 or five thousands entries in my application, this for loop will slow down the processs

Comment: See the last code which I have you will understand what I want , I can do it with for loop but I want it with good programming practice